# Python argument interpreter

Tags: python, input, arguments

Is there a correct way to read the arguments to a python application?

Example:

```
python game.py -server 127.0.0.1 -nick TheKiller1337
```

Is there a correct way of interpreting these argument?
As it is now I have a while-loop with some ifs. But it is getting rather large. Should I do a general class for argument reading, or is this already implemented in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html), [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) or [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html).

All three are in the standard library.

I recommend argparse. It is the newest of the three, and is IMO the easiest to use. It was introduced in version 2.7.

If using an older Python version, I would recommend optparse (or [get argparse for version 2.5 and 2.6](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse/1.1) from pypi)

Comment: It would be nice if you could specify the differences, at least mention that optparsre and getopt are not preferred over argparse.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using v2.7 or newer, you can use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse). The documentation has examples.

For earlier Pythons, [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) is usually the way to go.

The alternative is [`getopt`](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html), if you're rather be writing 'C'.

For each of these you would have to change your argument list to more conventional. Either of:

- `python game.py --server 127.0.0.1 --nick TheKiller1337`
- `python game.py -s 127.0.0.1 -n TheKiller1337`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) with only slight change to your initial plans. It would be like:

```
python game.py -s127.0.0.1 -nTheKiller1337
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `optparse`, because it is supported in 2.6 and because it has a nice interface, automatically generates help texts, and supports additional parameters, not just arguments.

Like this:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-e", "--event", dest="type", help="type of EVENT")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

if options.type == 'fubar':
  blah.blubb()
```

You get the idea.